# how to clear flutter project cache?

Tags: android, xcode, flutter, dart, build

I am facing issues with my flutter project.
Earlier it was working , then I upgraded to the latest version, iOS App build issues occurred,then I downgraded the flutter version many other dependencies issues occurred.

I implemented a command `flutter pub cache repair`.

Please guide me a similar command to clean all the previous dependencies cache.

Please don't provide `flutter clean`, I already implemented it.

Answer (score 1):

Delete the `pubspec.lock` file then run the command `flutter pub get` again.

Comment: lock file should never be deleted. It manages all your dependencies and deleting it and running flutter pub get again can bring breaking change

Comment: FYI- when you run get command .lock file recreate again and its system generated file nothing is breaked.

Comment: Yes, but it's not "generated" out of thin air. Pubspec.yaml is used for it. Now consider a package p in your yaml, with version a.b.c, which has a transitive dependency on another package p1 with a caret sign (^p1). 
Pubspec. locks *locks* these versions. So if you delete your lock file and run pub get again and if p1 has been upgraded with some breaking changes, then those breaking change will break your project as well(a p depends on p1)

Answer (score 1):

You can empty the entire projects cache to reclaim extra disk space or remove problematic packages.

run `flutter pub cache clean` in terminal at project directory